# How do I change the plot size of a regplot in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Something similar to the `fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)` of matplotlib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can declare `fig, ax` pair via `plt.subplots()` first, then set proper size on that figure, and ask `sns.regplot` to plot on that `ax`

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some artificial data
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,-0.5],[-0.5,1]], size=100)

# plot
sns.set_style('ticks')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
sns.regplot(data[:,0], data[:,1], ax=ax)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but just pass `figsize` to `plt.subplots()`; there is no need for an additional line of code to call `set_size_inches`.

Answer (score 5):

Or a little bit shorter:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some artificial data
data = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0], [[1,-0.5],[-0.5,1]], size=100)

# plot
sns.set_style('ticks')

g = sns.regplot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
g.figure.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
sns.despine()
```