# Adjusting Size of Seaborn Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've tried as many solutions as I could find on here, but I'm not having much luck on this.  I'm not sure if it's because some of my settings, but I am unable to reshape my Seaborn countplot.  Here's my code where I plot the figure:

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
sns.set(font_scale=1.3)
sns.countplot(x=df['QuarterYear'], hue=df['Modifier'])
ax = plt.gca()

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., p.get_height(), '%d' % int(p.get_height()), 
            fontsize=12, color='black', ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

I am also editing the legend and labeling my countplot columns in the same block of code.

I am using Jupyter Notebook %inline.  If anyone could explain what I am missing, that would be great.  I've tried many, many variations of these solutions, to no avail.

[How do I change the figure size for a seaborn plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594549/how-do-i-change-the-figure-size-for-a-seaborn-plot)

[How to make seaborn.heatmap larger (normal size)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519991/how-to-make-seaborn-heatmap-larger-normal-size)

[How do I change the plot size of a regplot in Seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556424/how-do-i-change-the-plot-size-of-a-regplot-in-seaborn)

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches( 16, 10)
```

Comment: That seemed to do it.  I think I'm misunderstanding the difference between plt.gcf() vs plt.gca()

Would you happen to know the difference?

Comment: `gcf` returns a `Figure`, a canvas to draw on it. `gca` returns an `Axes`, to make a plot. Very basically, in matplotlib, a figure contains one or more axes,  see https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html for more detail. In your case you need to resize the whole figure to have a larger display.

Comment: That is a great explanation.  Thank you very much!